Automatic discount creation for amount off products in shopify using Graphql
There is a option to create a automatic discount using API on shopify for amount off order. I want to create a automatic discount for amount off product using graphql
I tried to alter this JSON to apply the discount for products, but it didn't work. is there any possibility to achieve this?
https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-07/mutations/discountAutomaticBasicCreate
{
  "query": "mutation discountAutomaticBasicCreate($automaticBasicDiscount: DiscountAutomaticBasicInput!) { discountAutomaticBasicCreate(automaticBasicDiscount: $automaticBasicDiscount) { automaticDiscountNode { id automaticDiscount { ... on DiscountAutomaticBasic { startsAt endsAt minimumRequirement { ... on DiscountMinimumSubtotal { greaterThanOrEqualToSubtotal { amount currencyCode } } } customerGets { value { ... on DiscountAmount { amount { amount currencyCode } appliesOnEachItem } } items { ... on DiscountSpecificItems { specificItems { id } } } } } } } userErrors { field code message } } }",
  "variables": {
    "automaticBasicDiscount": {
      "title": "$100 off specific products over $500 for all customers",
      "startsAt": "2024-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "endsAt": "2024-12-31T23:59:59Z",
      "minimumRequirement": {
        "subtotal": {
          "greaterThanOrEqualToSubtotal": 500
        }
      },
      "customerGets": {
        "value": {
          "discountAmount": {
            "amount": 100,
            "appliesOnEachItem": false
          }
        },
        "items": {
          "specificItems": [
            { "id": 8885203271935 } 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

